# How to make Google Map reactive?

Tags: java, google-maps, vue.js

I currently struggle figuring out how to make the Google Map reactive, because when the component is mounted, the lat and lng are not chosen yet. Take a look at my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="google-map" id="sidebar-map"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["coordinates", "zoom"],

        data() {
            return {
                latLng: {
                    lat: 0,
                    lng: 0
                }
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.latLng = this.coordinates;

            let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('sidebar-map'), {
                zoom: this.zoom,
                center: this.latLng
            });
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: this.latLng,
                map: map
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there any way I can `new google.maps.Map` and `new google.maps.Marker` when the data is changed is this component?

Any idea or direction/hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch for a change in the `coordinates` or `zoom` props.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

I'm not familiar with the google maps API, but if its expensive (or breaks) when constantly rebound to the same element, you could consider storing the instance in a field of your component and using whatever API methods are available to programmatically change the zoom and coordinates.

Comment: Oh wow, ... Not sure how I didn't think of that solution. Thanks a lot!